# How to avoid repetition in file paths when using input/output shortcuts in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, filepath, gdal

Sorry if the title is vague, I'm not sure what terminology to use. Here is my problem. I use the following bits of code to shortcut INPUT/OUTPUT locations etc.:

```
BASE=~/J/ca/wgs
INPUT=~/J/ca/wgs/shps
OUTPUT=~/J/ca/wgs/rasters
SCRIPT=~/J/ca/wgs/scripts

gdal_translate $BASE/wgsraster.tif $OUTPUT/rast_1.tif
```

When running the gdal_translate I get the following error:

```
ERROR 4: `/home/user/J/ca/wgs/J/ca/wgs/wgsraster.tif' does not exist in the file system, and is not recognised as a supported dataset name.
```

Why is the bash shell reading the filepath (/J/ca/wgs/) twice and consequently not finding the .tif file in a non-existent location?

Just in case anyone asks, the .tif file is definitely in the $BASE location.

Comment: Add an `echo "$HOME"` just before that line. Does it output your homedir? `~` expands to the value of the `HOME` environment variable.

Comment: ~ is expanded to the home directory of user executing script, try `echo ~`

Comment: `echo $HOME` and `echo ~` both return `/home/user/J/ca/wgs`...how do I make `~` mean just `/home/user`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've overwritten your `$HOME` variable somehow; probably by accident.

Start a clean shell and see if `HOME` is correct there. If it is, then you're done (or it's you script doing it). If not, then you've got a problem in your `.profile` or `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc` or whatever your shell uses.

If you can't track down the cause of the problem right away, you can fix it temporarily:

```
export HOME=/home/user
```

Comment: I think it's the later, as the problem remains after restarting the OS. The export fix and clear diagnosis is great for now though, so thank you for that.